# How to reload JDialog?

Tags: java, refresh, jdialog

i have a frame and a button on it.

when people push the button the code is

```
    newForm = new AdminEdit(this, true);
    newForm.setVisible(true);
```

now i create the JDialog like this, and on dhe JDialog constructor, there are some options below

```
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM user ";
    conn = connection.connect();
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
    rs =pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()){

        name.setText(rs.getString("name"));
        sname.setText(rs.getString("sname"));
        mark.setText(rs.getString("mark"));
        pass.setText(rs.getString("pass"));
```

now i am setting the textfield with database but i create the JDialog first then textfield still empty,

i can set the textfields like this

```
    newForm = new AdminEdit(this, true, name, sname, mark, pass);
```

but i dont want to do it, i just want to create JDialog first and set some textfield after. how can i do this?

Comment: Add a method setSomeFields(name, sname, mark, pass) to the JDialog and do the calls name.setText(name)... in that method.

Comment: i have a method allready, the question is my method is in the JDialog class. i create the JDialog on the main form like this newForm = new AdminEdit(this, true) but now the textfields are empty, then i set the textfields but them still empty. i can set the textfields call via JDialog constructor like this new adminEdit(this,true,name,sname,pass) but i dont want to do it, i want to creat JDialog and after set texfields. name.reValidate() doesnt work.

Comment: In your constructor make the new of the JTextFields and add them to the JDialog's container. Your JDialog's method for setting the texts should be setStrings(String aName, String aSname, String aMark, String aPass) and not setTextFields(JTextField name, JTextField sname,...)